# Centering one section, titlesec

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, titlesec

Every once in a while I need to be able to center a section heading to place emphasis on it. Unfortunately there seems to be a conflict with `\centering` and the `titlesec` package which I use. I cannot figure out how to resolve the issue of the section being stretched across the line from the package documentation.

At the moment the only option I know of, which is terrible, is to call the `\titleformat` command before and after my section, which requires knowledge of the default which resides in my `.cls`. Ideally, I would actually like to be able to pass an option to the section command, for instance like `\section[centering]{my section}` but I dont know how to even look up what the options for the `\section` command are. I dont know how to alter section formatting without titlesec, perhaps it is time to learn, but I dont know where to begin.

[image]

In this MWE, comment out the titlesec package to see the issue resolved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries}{}{0in}{\thesection\hspace{1em}}

\tableofcontents

\section{A normal section}

\lipsum[4]

{\centering\section{a centered section}}

\lipsum[4]

\section{\centering a centered section}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Moving `\centering` into the argument seems to help: `\section{\centering a centered section}`

Comment: @dedded That has no change on the output for me

Comment: It centers it for me (lualatex and xelatex 2021), but I just noticed that it's _also_ centered in the TOC, which you probably don't want.

Comment: @dedded sorry you are right, unfortunately on both accounts though. Additionally the section will not be centered if you enact `\titleformat` at all prior. But the table of contents does still center, making it wrong on both accounts.

Comment: I added a `\titleformat` to the question to better represent the use case.

Answer (score 0):

`\centering` works by adjusting `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`.  `\makebox` centers (default) within a given width.  Varwidth shrinks the `\section` and `\null\hfil` balances the `\parendskip`.  Varwidth also absorbs the vertical space above and below.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries}{}{0in}{\thesection\hspace{1em}}

\tableofcontents

\section{A normal section}

\lipsum[4]

\section[A centered section]{\makebox[\linewidth]{A centered section}}

\lipsum[4]

\null\hfil\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\section{A centered section}
\end{varwidth}\csname @afterheading\endcsname
\vskip 2.3ex plus 0.2ex

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark those special sections somehow, so I propose to define a `\specialsection` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\Large\bfseries\ifSPECIAL\filcenter\fi}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\iffalse
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}
\fi
\newif\ifSPECIAL
\NewDocumentCommand{\specialsection}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \SPECIALtrue
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\section*}{\section}{#3}%
  \SPECIALfalse
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A normal section}

\lipsum[4][1-2]

\specialsection{A centered section}

\lipsum[4][1-2]

\section{A normal section}

\lipsum[4][1-2]

\section*{A normal starred section}

\lipsum[4][1-2]

\specialsection*{A special starred section}

\lipsum[4][1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]