# center title of acronyms when using \usepackage{acro}

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, acro

I am using texmaker and have printed a list of acronyms using the package `acro`. However, I am unable to center the heading of the acronyms (List of Acronyms) as this is a specific requirement for my thesis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{epa}{
  short=EPA,
  long=Environmental Protection Agency,}
\DeclareAcronym{re}{
  short=RE,
  long=Renewable Energy,}      
\begin{document}
The \ac{epa} and \ac{re} development
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Acronyms}
%\renewcommand{\listofacronyms}{\centering List of Acronyms}
\printacronyms[name=List of Acronyms]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want centered titles you might want to use the package `titlesec` with its `center` option.

Also, you shouldn't place `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Acronyms}` before `\printacronyms`: this might lead to a contentsline referring to a wrong page. Rather use `\acsetup{list/preamble=\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\acrolistname}}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{
  list/name = List of Acronyms ,
  list/preamble = \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\acrolistname}
}

\DeclareAcronym{epa}{
  short=EPA,
  long=Environmental Protection Agency
}
\DeclareAcronym{re}{
  short=RE,
  long=Renewable Energy
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Foo bar}
The \ac{epa} and \ac{re} development

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *really* want to only center the section title of the list of acronyms you can use the strategy from [Centering one section, titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632609/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0in}
  {\ifSPECIAL\centering\fi}

\newif\ifSPECIAL


\usepackage{acro}
\NewAcroTemplate[heading]{center}{\SPECIALtrue\section*{\acrolistname}}

\acsetup{
  list/heading = center ,
  list/name = List of Acronyms ,
  list/preamble = \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\acrolistname}
}

\DeclareAcronym{epa}{
  short=EPA,
  long=Environmental Protection Agency
}
\DeclareAcronym{re}{
  short=RE,
  long=Renewable Energy
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Foo bar}
The \ac{epa} and \ac{re} development

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the center environment as shown:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro} 

\DeclareAcronym{epa}{ short=EPA, long=Environmental Protection Agency,} \DeclareAcronym{re}{ short=RE, long=Renewable Energy,}
\def \bc{\begin{center}}
\def \ec{\end{center}}

\begin{document} 
    
    The \ac{epa} and \ac{re} development 
    %\renewcommand{\listofacronyms}{\centering List of Acronyms} 
    
    \bc \printacronyms[name=List of Acronyms] \ec
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Acronyms} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is just a quick fix. I'm sure there is a way to modify the \printacronyms command.

Comment: Thanks @kcortini , it works fine. I am trying to increase the space between the "List of the Acronyms" heading and the first acronym entry EPA. Do you know a good hack for this?

Comment: Maybe you could use the `parskip` package and change the `\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}` before the list of acronyms? Hope this works for you @george