# Increase vertical gap between acronym heading and the body using \usepackage{acro}

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, acronyms, acro

I am using texmaker and have printed a list of acronyms using the package acro. However, I am unable to increase the vertical space between the acronym heading "List of Acronyms", and the first entry of acronyms (EPA). using `\vspace*{40\baselineskip}` before printacronyms adds the space before "List of Acronyms" and using it after, adds the space after the last entry of acronyms (RE).

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{acro} 
    
    \DeclareAcronym{epa}{ short=EPA, long=Environmental Protection Agency,} \DeclareAcronym{re}{ short=RE, long=Renewable Energy,}
    \def \bc{\begin{center}}
    \def \ec{\end{center}}
    
    \begin{document} 
        
        The \ac{epa} and \ac{re} development 
        %\renewcommand{\listofacronyms}{\centering List of Acronyms} 
        
        \bc \printacronyms[name=List of Acronyms] \ec
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Acronyms} 
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please see my answer to your other question [center title of acronyms when using userpackage{acro}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638787/) regarding the centered title and my remark there about `\addcontentsline`.

`acro` has the option `list/preamble` with which you can add code between the heading if the list and the list itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro} 
    
\DeclareAcronym{epa}{
  short=EPA,
  long=Environmental Protection Agency
}
\DeclareAcronym{re}{
  short=RE,
  long=Renewable Energy
}

\acsetup{
  list/name = List of Acronyms ,
  list/preamble =
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\acrolistname}
    \vspace{4\baselineskip}% or whatever
}

\begin{document} 
        
The \ac{epa} and \ac{re} development 
        
\printacronyms
    
\end{document}
```

[image]